# How to set variable within 'script' section of gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml

I am trying to set an environment variable for my GitLab Runner based on the branch that the commit originated from.

I have 4 kubernetes clusters: staging, integration, production, and qa. Essentially I want to deploy my application to the proper cluster based on the branch I am pushing to.

```
image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
variables:
DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
services:
  - docker:dind
before_script:
  - docker info
stages:
  - publish
publish:
stage: publish
script:
  - if [ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" = "master" ]; then $ENVIRONMENT="production"; else $ENVIRONMENT="$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"; fi
  - echo $ENVIRONMENT
   .
   .
   .
  - kubectl apply -f cfg/${ENVIRONMENT}/web-deployment.yaml
only:
 - master
 - integration
 - qa
 - staging
```

Any time I run my script with a different form of the if statement I get the following error:

```
/bin/bash: line 83: =integration: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

So from what I can tell the variable is being set, but the script exits. I've seen several SO questions related to this problem, but nothing about how to set a variable and then continue a script. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: just use `ENVIRONMENT="production"` to assign variable not `$ENVIRONMENT=...`

Comment: Awesome thanks.

What are the differences between $VAR, VAR, "$VAR"?

Comment: `VAR` is used in the yaml syntax. `$VAR` and `"$VAR"` is bash syntax (used in the script section). With/Without quotes? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: Environmental Variables assignment is used as follow `VAR='value'`. The `$VAR='value'` is not valid syntax for assigning values. @Markus

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The comment above helped me figure it out. So I use a VERSION file that right now contains `0.0.0` which I manipulate to create other variables

```
  # determine what branch I am on
  - if [ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" = "master" ]; then ENVIRONMENT="qa"; else ENVIRONMENT="$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"; fi

  # determine patch number for semver
  - PATCH=`git log --pretty=oneline | wc -l | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`
  - VERSION=`cat VERSION`

  # drop trailing 0 from VERSION
  - VERSION=${VERSION%?}

  # set all env variables
  - TAG="${VERSION}${PATCH}"
  - IMAGE="${TAG}-${ENVIRONMENT}" # used for Kubernetes
  - API_HOST="https://api.${ENVIRONMENT}.my-app.com/"
  - WEB_HOST="https://www.${ENVIRONMENT}.my-app.com/"

  # pass enviornment variables to make 
  - ENVIRONMENT="$ENVIRONMENT" IMAGE="$IMAGE" API_HOST="$API_HOST" WEB_HOST="$WEB_HOST" make

  # make has a step that calls sed and replaces text inline in this file to prepare Kubernetes
  - kubectl apply -f cfg/web-deployment.yaml

  # create a tag in the repo after deployment is done
  - curl -X POST --silent --insecure --show-error --fail "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/repository/tags?tag_name=${TAG}&ref=${CI_COMMIT_SHA}&private_token=${GITLAB_TOKEN}"
```

Comment: Note: we are currently testing that is why I am deploying the "master" branch to the "qa" enviornment. We have other branches that match keywords corresponding to other environments.