# How to set the result of docker inspect to an env variable in gitlab-ci script

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, cicd

I am creating a test stage in my GitLab ci in which I create a container for Postgres DB. I will need to inspect the container and use the IP address as database URL in my flask application:

Here is a pseudo-code of what I want to do:

```
test:

  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "testing"
    - docker run -d -p 5434:5432 --rm --name pg_test_container --env-file test_database.env postgres:latest
    - db_host=docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' pg_test_container 
    - echo db_host
    - ...
    - ...
    - ...
    - ...
    - docker stop pg_test_container 
  tags:
    - test
```

How should I rewrite this part to make it work and set it to an env variable for me:
`db_host=docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' pg_test_container`

I will need to use it to create the `DATABASE_URL`:

`DATABASE_URL='postgresql://postgres:1234@db_host:5434/pg_db'`

Comment: did you try using services for your postgres: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/ ?

Comment: I tried and I am still stuck because of the permission errors. I have opened a ticket for IT to give permissions to the user I am using because with `sudo -i` I have no problem.
Thank you for your follow up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a shell script, you should be able to set a variable and use it:

```yaml
- db_host=$(docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' pg_test_container)
- echo "db_host='${db_host}'"
- DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:1234@${db_host}:5434/pg_db"
```

Other example: "[How to set variable within '`script`' section of `gitlab-ci.yml` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54415116/6309)"

As the [OP Amin Ba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11065874/amin-ba) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928591/how-to-set-the-result-of-docker-inspect-to-an-env-variable-in-gitlab-ci-script/69928688#comment123619863_69928688):

> The problem is with `docker inspect`.
> Actually, the problem is with the permissions of the user trying to run '`docker run`' command.

```sh
failed to read subscriptions from "/usr/share/rhel/secrets": 
open /usr/share/rhel/secrets/rhsm/rhsm.conf: permission denied
skipping entry in /usr/share/containers/mounts.conf: 
getting host subscription data: failed to read subscriptions from \"/usr/share/rhel/secrets\": 
open /usr/share/rhel/secrets/rhsm/rhsm.conf: permission denied"
```

Comment: @AminBa The second line is just a debug echo, which prints the name of the variable and then its value. The '=' is not for assignment, only to separate name and value.

Comment: @AminBa That means the first line did not assign any value to the variable. Replace, for testing, the first line with `- db_host="test"`, just to confirm assignment is working.

Comment: @AminBa That is the question indeed: I would make a simpler `docker inspect` (without assigning it to a variable), just to see if it outputs anything. Once that simpler `docker inspect` works, I would add back all the template parameters.

Comment: The problem is with docker inspect. Actually, the problem is with the permissions of the user trying to run 'docker run' command.
failed to read subscriptions from "/usr/share/rhel/secrets": open /usr/share/rhel/secrets/rhsm/rhsm.conf: permission denied

Comment: skipping entry in /usr/share/containers/mounts.conf: getting host subscription data: failed to read subscriptions from \"/usr/share/rhel/secrets\": open /usr/share/rhel/secrets/rhsm/rhsm.conf: permission denied"

Comment: @AminBa Is is related to https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/rootless-podman-issues/3366 and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1874621#c5 ?